# How do I install Custom Jar in HDInsight

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I am new to Hadoop/HDInsight.

I have followed the steps [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-using-json-in-hive/)  to create the jar package of SerDe. After the package `json-serde-1.1.9.9-Hive13-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is created the post says that I need to upload it to the head-node.

Does it mean that I have to RDP into the HDInsight VM and then manually upload the file?

If I don't have remote connection enabled to that VM what else can I do?

PS: The HDInsight Cluster is already provisioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to add it to the head-node for HDInsight.  If you upload the jar to the storage account associated with your cluster, you can access it using the add jar command used in your example.

```
add jar wasb://<storageaccount>@<containername>/<jarfolder>/json-serde-1.1.9.9-Hive13-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

For example:

```
add jar wasb://andrewsstorage@datacontainer/myjars/json-serde-1.1.9.9-Hive13-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

This is a more scaleable approach because the jar asset will remain after the HDI cluster is destroyed.

Comment: Didn't you get the container and storage account backwards? Can you edit your answer?

Comment: @Andrew Some more query. In the link given in my question there is a query which is written using SerDe. Is it possible that I can write the same query using the Hive editor of HDInsight Cluster in the browser?

Comment: @Sandesh - yes you can still use Query Console to write the same query but you will have to upload the JAR using the command line interface by RDP'ing in to the cluster.